# Problema com assign,

Tags: python

```
class transaction:
...
def send(from_key, to_key, SN):
    if SN in from_key.parts:
        str(from_key)+str(to_key)+str(SN)=transaction(SN,from_key,to_key,True)
```

SyntaxError: can't assign to operator

Não consigo atribuir uma `int` à classe "transaction"...
Vamos supor que

```
from_key = a
 to_key = b
 SN = 123
```

Quero chegar no seguinte resultado: 
`ab123 = transaction(SN,from_key,to_key,True)`

Manualmente (fora da função), funciona, mas quando tento automatizar na função recebo esse erro.

Update:

Preciso dar um nome para uma classe (transação) e determinei que esse nome será minha `from_key + to_key + SN`, no meu exemplo seria `ab123`. 
O problema é que cada vez que eu for realizar uma transação esse nome vai mudar, e criei uma função para realizar esse assing sozinho (`ab123 = transaction(...)`).
Como posso fazer isso dar certo?

Comment: Você não consegue fazer uma atribuição dinâmica desta forma. O que você quer é gerar dinamicamente a variável "ab123" conforme os parâmetros da função? E o que você fará com essa variável?

Comment: Eu quero gerar a variável de acordo com o que eu inseri na função send, no meu exemplo seria `send(a,b,123)`.
O meu problema é quando tento atribuir a variável à uma classe.
Por que `ab123 = transaction(...)` funciona e `str(from_key)+str(to_key)+str(SN)=transaction(...)` não?

Comment: Por que precisa fazer isso? O que fará com a variável?

Comment: Não é possível atribuir um valor a outro valor. No caso você está fazendo algo como `"a" + "b" +"123" = transaction(...)`.
O que você pode fazer e criar um dicionário e inserir estes valores usando a string gerada como chave.

Comment: como eu faria isso @fernandosavio?

Comment: vou formular uma resposta pra facilitar

Comment: A variável deve passar a ser uma transação, que por sua vez guarda informação da mesma @AndersonCarlosWoss 
Estou montando uma blockchain pro meu TCC, mas não tenho muito conhecimento na área de programação, se alguém estiver disposto a ajudar...

Comment: E por que ela não pode ser uma variável normal, tipo `trans = transaction(...)`?

Comment: Porque eu teria que fazer isso manualmente... eu quero que a função, de acordo com o que eu inseri nela, faça o assing automático.
Essa função realizará outras ações junto com essa...@AndersonCarlosWoss

Comment: Isso está me parecendo um [Problema XY](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/499/5878). Aconselho você a cogitar a ideia de [edit] a pergunta e explicar por texto o que está querendo fazer, no contexto geral. Não faz sentido definir uma variável dinâmica assim.

Comment: Atualizei o post tentando explicar melhor @AndersonCarlosWoss

Answer (score 0):

Tu pode criar um dicionário e usar a string gerada como chave:

```py
cache = dict()

def send(from_key, to_key, SN):
    if SN in from_key.parts:
        key = str(from_key) + str(to_key) + str(SN)
        cache[key] = transaction(SN, from_key, to_key, True)
```

Para recuperar o resultado de `transaction(...)` é só usar:

```py
print(cache['ab123'])  # ou qualquer que seja a chave
```

Comment: Retorna: `NameError: name 'cache' is not defined`

Comment: É preciso que cache esteja no escopo de onde tu está tentando acessá-la... Isso vai depender de como tu codificou.

Comment: estou programando na nuvem, em um jupyter notebook.

Comment: me refiro ao escopo do python mesmo.
olha [esse exemplo](https://repl.it/@fernandosavio/UnkemptBulkyOutsourcing) desde que se consiga acessar a variável cache dá pra guardar e ler informações

Comment: dessa forma que está no link ele não define a variável ab123.
Eu gostaria de poder definir a variável ab123 como sendo uma classe transação.

Comment: O resultado teria que ser o mesmo de `ab123 = transaction(...)`

Comment: João, não faz sentido você definir variáveis de forma dinâmica. Como acessará as variáveis depois se você não saberá os nomes das mesmas? O que você está fazendo definitivamente é um Problema XY e qualquer solução será gambiarra. Se quer um nome, passe por parâmetro uma *string*. Se quer persistir esse objeto em algum lugar, persista associando o nome ao objeto. Sem conhecer o problema inteiro, qualquer resposta aqui será mera especulação, com 96.37% de chance de ser gambiarra.

Comment: Um `dict()` serve justamente pra isso. No exemplo que te mandei poderia ser uma instância de `transaction`, sem problemas. A diferença é que ao invés de acessar como `ab123` se acessa `cache['ab123']`

Comment: O problema de se criar "variáveis dinâmicas" se resolve com `dict`, mas é como o @AndersonCarlosWoss comentou. O que sabemos do teu problema é muito raso, então só podemos torcer para que seja isso que tu precisa.

Comment: Desculpem por isso, como disse, não tenho conhecimento na área. Se quiserem dar uma olhada no código está aqui: https://github.com/veronamlima/notebook/blob/master/Blockchain%20V3%20(class).ipynb